# What kind of sources can integrate CKAN?

Tags: ckan

I would like to use CKAN in my company but firts I have some questions to solve yet. For example:

What kind of sources can integrate CKAN? I explain myself firts.

If my company has its data distributed in the following sources:

- Relational database (mysql, oracle)
- Non relational database (solr, cassandra, mongodb)
- Cloud (amazon s3, dropbox, google drive, google cloud storage)

Can CKAN access to this data sources for separate using a driver o some plugins and upload the data directly for example?

Can CKAN mix these data resources as a mashup tool?