# What CKAN integration/plugins are available for connecting to Hortonworks/HDFS/etc.?

Tags: ckan

I'm curious as to what options are available for integrating [CKAN](http://ckan.org) with external data sources as well as external data catalogs specifically as it relates to: Hortonworks / Cloudera / Hadoop / HDFS / Hive / HBase / etc.

- Are there methods for pulling data from [Hive](https://hive.apache.org/)/HDFS into CKAN and serving up the data from within CKAN?
- Are there methods for pointing to or referencing external data catalogs such as [Apache Atlas](https://atlas.apache.org/) from the Apache Hadoop stack/ecosystem?

Related questions I found:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976622/what-kind-of-sources-can-integrate-ckan
- [What kind of sources can integrate CKAN?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/12739/what-kind-of-sources-can-integrate-ckan)